# Rust plotters doesn't draw

Tags: rust

I'm trying to run one of the examples from rust's plotters user guide.  For some reason, whenI run the example, no image is written out to images/.  I looked through the whole project structure, no images are written to examples/ or otherwise.

Here's the output from cargo run:

```
plotters % cargo run 
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.06s
Running `target/debug/plotters`
```

Here's the code:

```
use plotters::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let root_drawing_area = BitMapBackend::new("images/0.1.png", (1024, 768))
        .into_drawing_area();

    root_drawing_area.fill(&WHITE).unwrap();

    let mut chart = ChartBuilder::on(&root_drawing_area)
        .build_cartesian_2d(-3.14..3.14, -1.2..1.2)
        .unwrap();

    chart.draw_series(LineSeries::new(
        (-314..314).map(|x| x as f64 / 100.0).map(|x| (x, x.sin())),
        &RED
    )).unwrap();

    root_drawing_area.present().unwrap();
}
```

Am I missing something?

Edit:

I added the explicit call to `root_drawing_area.present().unwrap();`, now I get a helpful error message:

```
% cargo run
   Compiling plotters v0.1.0 (/Users/sledge/Sandbox/plotters)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.82s
     Running `target/debug/plotters`
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: BackendError(DrawingError(ImageError(IoError(Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }))))', src/main.rs:18:33
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Comment: You should call [`root_drawing_area.present().unwrap();`](https://docs.rs/plotters/0.3.4/plotters/backend/trait.DrawingBackend.html#tymethod.present) to save the file explicitly and see if any error occurs. I'm betting that the `images` folder doesn't exist, but the error message should give you more details.

Comment: @Jmb, that's what it was.  For clarity's sake, what is the working director when I run cargo run?  Is it relative to the src, target, or somewhere else?  It's not crystal clear to me from the error where it expects the images/ directory to live.

Comment: File paths are typically relative to the *current directory* which is where you called `cargo run`.